# No state info with Chrome React.js tools

Tags: clojurescript, reactjs

I have the following ClojureScript code that uses the om library as a wrapper to React.js

```
(defn list-view [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IInitState
    (init-state [_]
      {:filter nil
       :selected-domain nil})

    om/IWillMount
    (will-mount [_]
      (th/poll filter-chan (fn[data]
                             (om/set-state! owner :filter data))))

    om/IRenderState
    (render-state [this state]
      (let [list-data (sort (list-data (:list app) (:filter state)))]
        (if (> (count list-data) 0)
          (dom/div #js {:className "sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset"}
            (dom/div #js {:className "bs-example well"}
              (apply dom/ul #js {:className "list-group"}
                (map (fn [text] (domain-list-item text  (:selected-domain state) owner))
                   list-data))))
          (dom/span nil))))))
```

This are the helper functions used in the code above

```
(defn list-data [alist filter-text ]
 (filter (fn [x] (cond (empty? filter-text) false
                       (nil? filter-text) false
                       (= filter-text "*") true
                       :else (> (.indexOf (.toLowerCase x) filter-text) -1))) alist))

(defn domain-list-item [text selected owner]
  (let [class-name (str "list-group-item" (if (= text selected) " isSelected" ""))]
    (dom/li #js {:className class-name}
      (dom/a #js
        {:href "#"
         :onClick (fn [event] (select-domain owner text))} text))))
```

Everything works as expected. The only thing that bothers me Is that I do not see any state info when I analyze the page with the React.js tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if sometimes the state is directly visible in the state area (e.g. for an input element) and sometimes it is hidden inside the __om_state object.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I often have to click on another component and then back on the component I'm interested in to see the state in the state area.  Perhaps that's the issue here?

Comment: No that isn't the problem in my case.